# Postgres count rows where value transitions from : A -> B -> A

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find the count of records where `position` of a `person_id` changes from `1 -> 2 -> 1`
 The transitions needs to be sorted in ascending order depending on the `timestamp`

Table Structure

```
timestamp  | person_id | position
--------------------------------
2020-01-01 | 5         |  1
2020-01-03 | 4         |  2
2020-02-04 | 7         |  1
2020-02-05 | 5         |  2
2020-02-06 | 7         |  2
2020-02-09 | 5         |  1
```

Here, the output will be `1`, since `person_id`:`5` transitions from `1 -> 2 -> 1`

```sql
select count(*)
from table_name t1
join table_name t2
  on t1.person_id = t2.person_id
 and t1.position = 1 
 and t2.position = 2
 and t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp;
```

Using this query I can find transition from `1 -> 2`
But I can't figure out how to again search for the transition to `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
select person_id
from t
where position in (1, 2)
group by person_id
having string_agg(position::text order by timestamp) like '%1,2,1%';
```

Edit:

The above would not find 1 --> 2 --> 2 --> 1.  For this, use:

```
having string_agg(position::text order by timestamp) like '%1%2%1%';
```

EDIT II:

Your query is not correct because it counts transitions, not persons.  But it can easily be extended:

```
select count(distinct person_id)
from table_name t1 join
     table_name t2
     on t1.person_id = t2.person_id and
        t1.position = 1 and
        t2.position = 2 and
        t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp and
     table_name t12
     on t12.person_id = t2.person_id and
        t12.position = 1 and
        t2.timestamp < t12.timestamp;
```

Comment: `position` is an integer, so won't work with `string_agg()`

Comment: @saintlyzero . . . That is easily tweaked for.

Comment: Nice solution, this will match aggregates such as "11,2,1", "1,2,12" and the like though. If position can only be 1 or 2 this should work

Comment: @cogitoergosum . . . Hint:  `WHERE`.  What you way is not true.

Comment: Missed that, my bad. I'm not sure if that `where` is correct, though, as that may strip out other relevant rows if position can be different from 1 and 2. 1->2->3->1 will be considered the same as 1->2->1 which may or may not be correct

Comment: @cogitoergosum . . . My understanding of the question is that only transitions between the two states are important.  The OP could clarify, though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good use case for the `LEAD` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-window.html).

Edited:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM(
SELECT position as p1, lead(position) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY timestamp) as p2, lead(position, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY timestamp) as p3
FROM table_name) qry where qry.p1=1 and qry.p2=2 and qry.p3=1
```

Comment: I tried this. Getting an error: window functions are not allowed in WHERE

Comment: correct, you'll need a subquery then. Edited my answer